# Create a C# Generic class for repeated code

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, generics, delegates

Hi I have the following code through out my project.

```
if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)    
    return new GetDictionaryPlResponse
    {
        Responses = new Responses
        {
            IsSuccess = false,
            ResponseMessage = "There response data is invalid!"
        }
    };
```

I am trying to simplify this using Generic and have done the following.

```
if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    var returnValue = ReturnNullFoundClass
                      .ResponseType<GetDictionaryPlResponse>();
    returnValue.Responses = ReturnNullFoundClass.ResponseNullFound();
    return returnValue;
}
```

And here is extention class.

```
public static class ReturnNullFoundClass
{

    public static Responses ResponseNullFound()
    {
        return new Responses
        {
            IsSuccess = false,
            ResponseMessage = "There response data is invalid!"
        };
    }

    public static T ResponseType<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

i was wondering if there was a way where this can be simplified further using the Func method instead of declaring 3 lines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which 3 lines do you refer to?

Comment: you could create a responsefactory based on the HttpStatusCode

Comment: var returnValue = ReturnNullFoundClass
                      .ResponseType<GetDictionaryPlResponse>();
    returnValue.Responses = ReturnNullFoundClass.ResponseNullFound();
    return returnValue;

Comment: Can you give me a example of ResponseFactory. Or any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a static factory you could try something like so:

```
public class Responses 
{
    // Some code here
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
}

public interface IResponsesContainer
{
    Responses Responses { get; set; }
}

public class GetDictionaryplResponse : IResponsesContainer
{
    public Responses Responses { get; set; }
}

public enum ResponsesTypes
{
    NullFound
}

public static class ResponsesFactory 
{
    public static IResponsesContainer CreateContainer<TContainer>(ResponsesTypes responsesType)
        where TContainer : IResponsesContainer, new()
    {
        var container = new TContainer();
        switch(responsesType)
        {
            case ResponsesTypes.NullFound:
                container.Responses = new Responses()
                {
                    IsSuccess = false,
                    ResponseMessage = "There response data is invalid!"
                };
                return container;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Abstract your `GetDictionaryPlResponse` class as an interface and return the interface.

This way is a bit more verbose in terms of definitions but it is pretty flexible for enhancements in the future.

If you do not want `Responses` on your `IResponsesContainer` to have a public setter then you would need to change this up a bit. Maybe use an abstract class instead, or change how the interface works.

**EDIT You call the method like so**

```
var container = ResponsesFactory.CreateContainer<GetDictionaryplResponse>(ResponsesTypes.NullFound);
```

Comment: This looks good. How would i call this method

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Spot on this is exactly what i was looking for thanks

Comment: If this satisfies your requirements I would appreciate you marking it as the answer. If not, or you need more, let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do to simplify your code is to work as `DBNull.Value` work. One way to implement it is as follow :

```
    public class DictionaryPIResponseNullFound
    {
        public static readonly GetDictionaryPlResponse Value = new GetDictionaryPlResponse
        {
            Responses = new Responses
            {
                IsSuccess = false,
                ResponseMessage = "There response data is invalid!"
            }
        };
    }
```

Then you can call it that way :

```
    if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)    
        return DictionaryPIResponseNullFound.Value;
```

Comment: I have looked at this way but you would need to declare Static class with concrete type everywhere. I wanted to do using generics where i pass the T in and and the assign Response to it.

Comment: In the first place why do you need to have different kind of response when you response is esentially the same everywhere? (Data invalid)
If you just happen to have different generic message you can just create different static readonly values (one for each)